# does flask app require licensing or can it be distributed freely

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask

So, basically me and my team are planning to create python flask app, and we wanted to know whether the app is required to be licensed or it can be distributed as we wish?
i am not sure if i am able to convey exactly what i mean, but hopefully this help you understand what i am trying to ask, if not please let me know, and i will try  to clarify my question.

we have created the required python script, that will eventually be converted to a flask app, but the thing is we dont know if its freely distributeable or it needs to be licensed or follow a particular license requirements.

Comment: You should read the [license](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/license/) to have a complete answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you could find info like this on official repo of projects like flask.

https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/main/LICENSE.rst

> Copyright 2010 Pallets
>
> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
> modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
> met:
>
> Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
> this list of conditions and the following disclaimer. Redistributions
> in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of
> conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or
> other materials provided with the distribution. Neither the name of
> the copyright holder nor the names of its contributors may be used to
> endorse or promote products derived from this software without
> specific prior written permission. THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE
> COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED
> WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
> MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.
> IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR
> ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
> DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE
> GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
> INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER
> IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR
> OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF
> ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

Answer (score 1):

The flask project is under the BSD-3-Clause license (BSD-new).

> This version allows unlimited redistribution for any purpose as long as its copyright notices and the license's disclaimers of warranty are maintained. The license also contains a clause restricting use of the names of contributors for endorsement of a derived work without specific permission.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#3-clause_license_(%22BSD_License_2.0%22,_%22Revised_BSD_License%22,_%22New_BSD_License%22,_or_%22Modified_BSD_License%22))

Answer (score 0):

You can see the information [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/main/LICENSE.rst), but also remind you that while open source licenses generally allow free distribution of your application, they may come with certain obligations or restrictions. It is best to consult a legal professional or familiarize yourself with the specific terms of the license you choose to ensure compliance.

Additionally, if your Flask application depends on third-party libraries or frameworks, you also need to consider their licenses.